# Round off to the nearest ten minutes - Snowflake/SQL

Tags: timestamp, rounding, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

What's the best way to round off a timestamp to the nearest ten minutes in Snowflake/SQL? Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Convert to seconds since Epoch, `ROUND()`, and convert back to `TIMESTAMP`:

```
SELECT TO_TIMESTAMP(ROUND(EXTRACT(EPOCH_SECOND FROM CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)/(10*60))*(10*60));

=> 2019-12-04 07:10:00.000
```

(The query above was run at 07:13 UTC)

**Note** that you can convert back to your local timezone by using `TO_TIMESTAMP_[L]TZ()`, but it is generally impossible to correctly adjust a `TIMESTAMP_TZ` that is *not* your local timezone when the adjustment would imply a Daylight Savings Time change.  Then you have to know the name of the timezone in which the `TIMESTAMP_TZ` originated so that you can `CONVERT_TIMEZONE()` the adjusted value to the correct offset.

This however works when my session timezone is `Europe/Oslo`:

```
SELECT TS, TO_TIMESTAMP_TZ(ROUND(EXTRACT(EPOCH_SECOND FROM TS)/(10*60))*(10*60)) RTS
FROM (SELECT TIMESTAMP_TZ_FROM_PARTS(2020, 3, 29, 1, 59, 59 , 0, 'Europe/Oslo') TS);

=> 2020-03-29 01:59:59.000 +0100      2020-03-29 03:00:00.000 +0200
```